# Angular 4 - What is the right way to "wait for operation"?

Tags: javascript, angular

*I'm encountering a simple problem which has a hacky solution of `setTimeout(...,0)`.*

Looking at this simple code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input value='Fill Data' type='button' (click)='fill()'/>
      <span *ngFor="let o of Items" class='mySpan'>Span To Detect<br></span>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  Items:Array<number> = new Array<number>();

  fill()
  {
   this.Items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   this.analyzeDom(); //this has to run here
  }

  analyzeDom()
   {
      alert($("div .mySpan").length) // "0"

     //BUT if I set this hacky trick , it works
     // setTimeout(function (){  alert($("div .mySpan").length)},0) // "10"
   }
}
```

If I click the button  , the alert shows "0". I understand why it's happening.   It's becuase Angular didn't complete its cycle to actually populate the `ngFor`.

However - doing this trick with `setTimeout(..,0)` seems a bit hacky to me and I prefer not to trust on it.

**Question:**

What is the *right* way to "wait for operation" in Angular ? (so that I'll see "10") ?

[**Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VKN3v98uXf3aL7oVvuUy?p=preview)

Comment: By using [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) - `ngOnInit` or the different `ngDoCheck` methods

Comment: @mhodges But it's on demand by clicking the button, and this button can be clicked much after  those hooks have already occured

Comment: What is the reason you want to make it synchronous and delay function until DOM would be updated? Isn't better to read length from current model istead of DOM like `alert(this.Items.length)` ?

Comment: @Kuba Nope ,  becuase i'm checking each element at scroll : "`IsInViewPort(elemenet)`" so the Array itself doesn't help much.

Comment: @yurzui you should really provide them as answers so we can upvote : p

Comment: See answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35826628/3696510

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) You can force Angular to update the DOM by calling `cdRef.detectChanges`

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

analyzeDom(){
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  alert($("div .mySpan").length)
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XFlV5saTLtiNT8QPOlCO?p=preview)**

As `setTimeout` is macrotask therefore it is running next digest cycle.
It means that after calling `setTimeout` all components tree will be checked

`cdRef.detectChanges` doesn't call `appRef.tick()`. It only executes change detection component itself and its children.

2) or you can wait until Angulat has updated DOM by subscribing to `zone.onMicrotaskEmpty`

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
...
this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => this.analyzeDom());
```

**Note: first operator can cause memory leak.** See https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6905

Subscribing to `onMicrotaskEmpty` doesn't call change detection cycle

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1MS3w4GP7zv5tYZD2hn8?p=preview)**

Comment: Can you please explain how differ `setTimeout(...0)` is as opposed to your solutions ??

Comment: @Royi setTimeout works because it bumps the function you pass to it into the next evaluation cycle. So in your code you make your changes, then Angular detects those changes and alters the DOM accordingly. After that pass through the code, your timeout function executes. Really isn't that bad a solution except that it's not an Angular solution and therefore hacky. The solutions listed above explicitly say execute my code after the dom has been updated.

Comment: @SethWhite Thank for the clarification , however , I'm searching for a good article about `onMicrotaskEmpty ` ( for learning purpose) - still haven't found any

Comment: @yuruzi - Thank you . (like always).

Comment: Did you import `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';`?