# How to know when element has been added to DOM on Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I need to manipulate a DOM element that is hidden by a `*ngIf` directive:

```
<div *ngIf="myBoolean">
    <canvas id="myElement"></canvas>
</div>
```

After a button click, I run the following method:

```
showMyElement(){
    this.myBoolean = true; //This shows the div containing myElement
    console.log(document.getElementById('myElement')); //This gives me null
}
```

But if I get `myElement` by clicking on another button after it is visible, I don't get `null`. I guess that when I get it the first time, it hasn't been added to the DOM yet. How can I know when `myElement` has been added to the DOM? Is there something like `(ngModelChange)` but for when added to the DOM? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually run change detection cycle to make sure that your view is updated

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

showMyElement(){
    this.myBoolean = true; 
    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // redraw view
    console.log(document.getElementById('myElement')); //This gives me null
}
```

See also

- [Angular 4 - What is the right way to "wait for operation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457149/angular-4-what-is-the-right-way-to-wait-for-operation)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!