# Adding event listener to dynamic element in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some description text from an API that I am inserting as HTML into the DOM.

```
<div class="activity-description" [innerHTML]="description"></div>
```

The description is set within ngOninit();

```
if (this.eventDetail.description.length > 255) {
   this.description = this.eventDetail.description.substring(0, 255) + '<span class="more-description"> ...Learn More</span>';
}
```

I am trying to add an event listener to the "more-description" class within the ngAfterViewInit()

```
var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.more-description');
    if (el)
        el.addEventListener('click', this.displayFullDescription());
```

The element is null and does not allow the event listener to be attached. How do I add this event listener to html elements that are dynamically added?

Comment: Try to run `cdRef.detectChanges()` before traversing

Comment: Where would I run the function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can manually render view by calling `cdRef.detectChanges`:

```
constuctor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.eventDetail.description.length > 255) {
    this.description = this.eventDetail.description.substring(0, 255) +
                      '<span class="more-description"> ...Learn More</span>';
  }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.more-description');
}
```

**Update**

Perhaps you made some mistake in this code:

```
el.addEventListener('click', this.displayFullDescription());
```

I don't know what `displayFullDescription` function does.

Here is working example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'event',
  template: `
    <div class="activity-description" [innerHTML]="description"></div>
  `,
})
export class Event {
  @Input() eventDetail: any;

  description: string;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.eventDetail.description.length > 255) {
       this.description = this.eventDetail.description.substring(0, 255) + '<span class="more-description"> ...Learn More</span>';
    }
  }

  displayFullDescription() {
    this.description = this.eventDetail.description;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.more-description');
    if(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', this.displayFullDescription.bind(this));
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ULY7QZMKly8YymSk8Sv5?p=preview)**

**Note:** It would be better if you store handler in class property so that you can unsubscribe later.

Comment: this is not working. The event listener is never attached.

Comment: So the issue is that the description is returned by a service call. So now the question is: "How do I attach an event listener to a dynamic element appended after a service call?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457149/angular-4-what-is-the-right-way-to-wait-for-operation/43457771#43457771

Comment: Create plunker to reproduce it. As i said early you can call `cdRef.detectChanges()` to update view after initialization `description`

Comment: I got around the issue with span tags in the HTML. <div class="activity-description"><span [innerHTML]="description"></span><span (click)="displayFullDescription()">...Learn More</span></div>

Comment: Nice answer, just one question, why you did not call the function `displayFullDescription()` directly, why you used `this.displayFullDescription.bind(this)` instead?

Comment: @SlimenTN addEventListener takes second parameter called listener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener It should be function. If we call `displayFullDescription()` directly then the **result** of execution will be passed as a listener but we need to pass function with right context. That's why I use `bind` here

Comment: How to pass parameter when call `el.addEventListener('click', this.displayFullDescription.bind(this));`

Comment: @Sanyami Vaidya Try `el.addEventListener('click', this.displayFullDescription.bind(this, param))` or `el.addEventListener('click', () => this.displayFullDescription(param))`