# How to asynchronously add items to owl-carousel using Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, owl-carousel-2

I've imported owl-carousel libraries into my Angular2 CLI project, which displays correctly if I have:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" #carousel >
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>
```

but I need the data for the carousel to load asynchronously. So in my component's typescript I've updated to:

```
...
this.getData().subscribe(
        d => {
            this.data = <Results>d;
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
...
```

Then in my html for the component I now have:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" #carousel >
    <div *ngFor="let item of data.items">
          <h1>Item name</h1>
          {{item.name}}
      </div>
</div>
```

However it doesn't display correctly. The data is loaded but the carousel doesn't set itself up properly. I've experimented with calling the element's owlCarousel() after the data has loaded but still didn't fix it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How do you initialize plugin?

Comment: I installed owl.carousel using npm install --save owl.carousel then imported the js and styles. I initialise the carousel using this.owlElement = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
this.owlElement.owlCarousel();

Comment: Try running `cdRef.detectChanges()` after `this.data = <Results>d;` and then call `this.owlElement.owlCarousel()` See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457149/angular-4-what-is-the-right-way-to-wait-for-operation

Comment: Coul it be because you're selecting one `item` from the `data` variable to itterate? `<div *ngFor="let item of data.items">`?

Comment: Thanks yurzil! calling cdRef.detectChanges() fixed it. If you add that as the answer I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can initialise the carousel in ngAfterViewInit() rather than detecting change and updating the DOM.

Also think about clearing the carousel object in ngOnDestroy().

Someone else's example here: [plunkr example](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/FnZVxB)